# Type.GetType() doesn't find dynamically created type

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I'm creating types dynamically by using Reflection.Emit. When I try to resolve a type created that way, I either get a return value of null or an error is thrown, that the type couldn't be found.

I've tried to use search like this:

```
Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyType, FullQualifiedAssemblyName", false);
```

Is there anything special to have a look on? Perhaps even through the process of creation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add sample code how you create own type and what do with it?

Comment: this overloading for _Type.GetType_ working [If the type is **in the currently executing assembly** or **in Mscorlib.dll**, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx), but as i understand when you create type dynamically you, possibly internal, create another assembly where placed created types, that's why you can't get it